# MySQL too many prepared statements

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to see what the prepared statements are that are associated with this error:

```
(OperationalError) failed to prepare the MySQL query: 
Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 20000)
```

One of several processes might be responsible for this problem and I'm trying to figure out which one it could be the easiest way I can think of, which is to see the text of the prepared statements and track it back to the source.

Is there any way to see what these prepared statements are so I can find the guilty party?

Comment: Turn on the query log.

Answer (score 0):

To see how many prepared statements are currently open, you can run:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_%prepare%';
```

Which gives you something like:

```
Variable_name      | Value
-------------------+--------
Com_prepare_sql    | 2
Com_stmt_prepare   | 2
Com_stmt_reprepare | 0
Com_xa_prepare     | 0
```

To read the actual statements, you will need to look in the general query log for a while, and then read from it.
I like using a table for the general log:

```
-- set up
TRUNCATE TABLE mysql.general_log;
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

-- wait for some time
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';

-- read results
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log WHERE argument LIKE 'prepare%' OR argument LIKE 'execute%';
```

You can see statements being prepared and executed:

```
command_type | argument
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
Query        | prepare st from "select * from people where name = ?"
Query        | execute st Using @name
```